# Referencing a js maven dependency from a JSP

Tags: jsp, maven, struts2, dependencies

I don't know if this a dumb question but as I'm new to Maven I don't really know how to deal with this:

I'm currently working on a webapp (struts2) project using `Maven` project structure, and I've just added a new dependency I want to work with: `jqgrid-4.6.0` (Jquery grid-view plugin).

I added the dependency to my `pom.xml` just fine and now problems come when I have to include the `js` files inside that dependency into a `JSP`. If I had done it the old way (without using Maven dependencies) I would put all the `js` files comming inside the jar into the `Project_root/src/main/webapp/js` directory in my project and reference them like this:

```
<script src="../js/some_file_name.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I'm not sure how to deal with this by using the dependency instead of putting the extracted .jar inside my js directory..

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using webjars (maybe you already do so). It allows you to add any type of Javascript library as a dependency within your Maven project.

In your case you can just add the following dependency to your maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jqgrid</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm not sure how this would work in a struts 2 application, but in a normal servlet 3 compliant server you could reference the file by using:

```
<script src="webjars/jqgrid/4.6.0/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

It might be that you need to put the applications context path in front of the relative URL.

The URL should then be something like:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/jqgrid/4.6.0/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

See the [webjars documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems to be what I was looking for, although I don't really have the knowledge now to understand why this works as I'm fairly new to `Maven`.. 

So no need to put manually all the `js` files inside my webapp directory just like a "normal" plugin install? Including that dependency to my `pom.xml`will do all th work?

Comment: I'm currently testing with another jquery plugin, the `struts2-jquery-plugin` from group `com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery` and it seems to work without referencing it inside the JSPs, just added the dependencies to my `pom.xml` and it's frankly more convenient than having all plugin files and stuff inside the `/lib` folder

Comment: Yes in general you should not have to put any manual JS files in your web directory when using webjars. I'm not sure what you mean with a "normal" plugin install? What framework have you used in the past, so I can maybe explain it in your terms. I think also the struts2-jquery-plugin uses a custom JSP tag to put the same line in the resulting html file.

Comment: this is what I call a "normal" install:
[link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install). 

I'm working with struts2, building a webapp using `Maven` project structure. I need to display and filter some data so that's why I'm trying to install some jquery plugins. I just wanted to learn a little bit about working with javascript or jQuery plugins using Maven so I don't have to manually install it into my `/lib`folder.

Sorry for my poor explanations but it's all I got with my basic knowledge :(

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to put them as a dependency? Are js file is not the part of you project?

Usually non-java (eq non jar/war/ear etc) packages are added as a part of a project.  I've seen some packages of frameworks like jQuery for maven, but this is not a typical.  You may build your own war for jQuery, but it would be a dummy separate war with its own life independent from yours in terms of deployment.

Comment: I'm new to web development and new to Maven, so I have little to no experience in building webapps... I thought it would be a good practice to include all external "things" I need (that includes jquery and javascript plugins) as Maven dependencies, but I might have misunderstood...